# Dynamic programming algorithm to find minimum cost

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve this question from Jeff Erickson's algorithms book.
[Premise of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1JLB.png)

The question is this:

Describe a dynamic programming algorithm to compute, given the tree
T and an integer k, the minimum clustering cost of any subset of k
vertices in T. For full credit, your algorithm should run in O(n2k2) time.

Not really sure how to get started. What should I memoize? The maximum cost considering a vertex to be the root of a subset? I was thinking of doing a level order traversal and trying out all combinations of subset roots, which clearly would not fit into the time complexity requirements.

I need some guidance as to how to approach this problem in particular and such problems in general.

Comment: Always look for a way to solve the problem recursively first; memoisation can easily be added on top afterwards. Solving recursively means looking for a way to break the problem into subproblems, whose solutions can be combined somehow into a solution to the original problem. Often with problems on trees, subtrees correspond naturally to subproblems.

Comment: I meant to say recursively. I get what you are saying, but I can't think of a recursive approach. Any ideas on how to get started?

Comment: I suggest trying a simpler problem that uses some of the same ideas first: Finding a maximum-size independent set on a tree.